# I cannot read external files from the application image created using the Java JLink tool

Tags: java, javafx, resources, java-11, jlink

I cannot read external files from the application image that I created using JLink tool(`mvn javaf:jlink`) when the application is running. The external files are placed in the *resources* folder. This is the error that I got:

```
ERROR ExecutorOfFiles Script failed to read or load: SampleScript.jsh
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /com.luisosv/com/luisosv/SampleScript.jsh
        at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem.checkNode(JrtFileSystem.java:494)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem.getFileContent(JrtFileSystem.java:253)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem.newByteChannel(JrtFileSystem.java:351)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.newByteChannel(JrtPath.java:696)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(JrtFileSystemProvider.java:302)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:370)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:421)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3205)
        at com.luisosv@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.luisosv.ExecutorOfFiles.loadSnippetsFromFile(ExecutorOfFiles.java:55)
```

I'm using the following to read the external file:

```
String sourceCode = new String(Files.readAllBytes(
                Paths.get(
                        this.getClass().getResource(scriptFileName).toURI())));
```

However, using the application from command-line it works fine `mvn javafx:run`.

I've read that the application image once created, cannot be updated or patched. For any changes, a new application needs to be deployed from https://www.studytrails.com/java/java-9/java-9-jlink/, and I don't know if that is the reason or something else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug in the resource lookup for the jrt filesystem affecting Java versions prior to 13.

When I run the following code snippet:

```
Path p = Paths.get(Object.class.getResource("Object.class").toURI());
System.out.println(p);
System.out.println(Files.exists(p));
```

All JDKs from 9 to 12 produce the following output:

```
/java.base/java/lang/Object.class
false
```

Starting with JDK 13, the output is

```
/modules/java.base/java/lang/Object.class
true
```

Likewise, `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(Object.class.getResource("Object.class").toURI()))` produces the exception `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /java.base/java/lang/Object.class` similar to the exception in your question, showing a path with a module name but no preceding `/modules`, for JDK 9 to 12.

So, just switching to JDK 13 or newer would solve your problem.

---

Note, however, that using

```
byte[] b = Object.class.getResourceAsStream("Object.class").readAllBytes();
```

or cleaner

```
try(InputStream is = Object.class.getResourceAsStream("Object.class")) {
    byte[] b = is.readAllBytes();
}
```

works on all versions from 9 to 14. So I recommend using `getResourceAsStream` in the first place instead of the `URL` → `URI` → `Path` detour.

---

That said, you should not use the `String(byte[])` constructor. The outcome of this constructor will depend on the current environment, using the system’s default character encoding whereas the actual encoding of your embedded resource will never change.

Use, e.g. `new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, or specify whatever your resource is encoded with.

Answer (score 1):

Loading a resource as file does not work if the file is packed in a JAR file. Use `getResourceAsStream(...)` instead:

```
new String(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(scriptFileName).readAllBytes());
```

Comment: The OP doesn’t try to load the resource as file. His code uses `URL` → `URI` →`Path`, but not `File`.

Comment: @Holger `Path` is just a new name for a `File`. Both classes are designed to work on files in the file-system, hence it is a bad idea to use it to load packed resources.

Comment: If that was true, introducing `Path` was pointless. But a `Path` is not just another name for `File`, as a `Path` does not need to belong to the default filesystem. There is an implementation for zip files, which of course can also read jar files, as well as an implementation for module images.

Comment: @Holger If that is true why your post does not contain a working solution via `Path` without using `getResourceAsStream(..)`?

Comment: Seems you have reading difficulties. The answer clearly shows that the bug has been solved in JDK 13 but says that `getResourceAsStream` works in all versions (and is simpler anyway).

Comment: @Holger OK, but that is very well hidden as you need to derive the real answer from what you have written. When writing long answers you should start with the most important fact: That it does not work on Java prior to v13 because of a bug. That should be the first sentence. You have a great Java knowledge but I would assume for 90% of the users your answer is too long and the relevant details are scattered among the post (just my personal opinion).

Comment: I’m not sure, how I could write it even earlier than right in the first sentence. Right after that, there is a direct comparison between the affected and the fixed version. And any reader who manages to get to the point where I also recommend `getResourceAsStream` should have seen it. But I take you comment as suggestion to improve it.

Comment: @Holger The first sentence need to much knowledge - you can't expect that everybody knows what `jrt ` is and why it is relevant here. Typical users have 10% of your knowledge and less. An answer should consider that especially as the asker has not much Java experience. Can I rewrite your answer to show you how in my opinion a well structured easy to understand answer should look?

Comment: When an answer to a question states that there is a bug, it doesn’t matter whether you know what the mentioned component is or not, it should be obvious that it is related to the question, as otherwise, it wasn’t mentioned in the very first sentence of an answer. Besides that, when you search the question for occurrences of “jrt” you will see immediately why it is relevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220375/discussion-between-robert-and-holger).